# How to add comma to a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column list as

```
['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']
```

I want to display as

```
Text1, Text2, Text3
```

The length of the array may vary.

Current input dataframe

[image: Current Output]

Expected :

[image]

Comment: Please share sample input dataframe and expected output for better understanding.

Comment: Attached the current dataframe

Comment: Is it an array of 3 strings 'Text1', 'Text2', and 'Text3' ?

Comment: `df['Column3'].apply(', '.join)` or `df['Column3'].str.join(', ')` should do it

Comment: yes its an array of strings (length may vary), i would need my dtaframe column to be separated with comma

Comment: @mary It will work with varied lengths too.

Comment: I am getting this error print('filename', df2['Column3'].values.str.join(', '))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Get rid of `.values` should just be `df2['Column3'].str.join(', ')`. Though depending on the dtype of the column this may or may not work.

Comment: can you do `print(df.head(5).to_dict()` and paste the output in your main body.

Comment: by removing values , it would come with index for my column, str.join didnt work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your problem with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Sno": [1,2], "column1": ["A","B"], "Column2": ["C", "D"], "Column3":[['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3'], ['Text4', 'Text5', 'Text6']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

To get your desired outcome you need this line:

```
df['Column3'] = df['Column3'].map(lambda row: (', ').join(row))
```

Output

```
  Sno  column1  Column2 Column3
0   1      A       C    Text1, Text2, Text3
1   2      B       D    Text4, Text5, Text6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `str.join()` function on the series:

```py
df['Column3'].str.join(', ')
```

Comment: can you please check my current dataframe attached. i have other columns which need not be merged

Comment: Edited my answer :)